# auto-close HTML tags in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm using Sublime Text 2, and I'm sure there must be a way to make it auto-close XML/HTML tags, the way for example Notepad++ can.

Is there a way to have it add `</div>` immediately after I type `<div>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As zoli's answer states, you can use snippets/completions to auto complete tags as you start typing them.  But there should be some built into sublime.  For example, as you start to type `<div>`, you should see a drop down box with matching snippets. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to pick one and arrow keys to go up or down in the list.  For html tags, it will automatically adds the closing tag and puts the cursor in between them.

Another option is: use `Edit > Tag > Close Tag`.  The hotkeys are displayed in the file menu.  It automatically adds the closing tag if you already added an opening tag.

Answer (score 5):

Sublime's built-in snippets differ for HTML and XML.

For HTML, you can type `<div` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete `<div></div>`.

For XML, though, it's different. You first type `<` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete to `<p></p>` with the `p` tags multiple-selected by default. So you can then type `foo` and have it autocomplete to `<foo></foo>`. Once you've named your element, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump to the content of the element.

You can use `Edit > Tag > Close Tag` equally on both HTML and XML.

Answer (score 3):

[SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) has pretty good completions for HTML. You can type a tag name (w/o the opening brace) and press Tab to complete both the opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Emmet plugin](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime).

To create a closed `div`, simply type `div` then press the `Tab` key.